# Count how many users are registered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can I count how many users are registered on my firebase?

I am using react.

Comment: hi Jader, can you post your firebase structure? thanks

Comment: I slightly reworded your question to make it more understandable, also fixed the question title. We have *tags* here, so there is no point in using "tag" names in the question title. That is just redundant.

Comment: @GhostCat no point in using tags in the title?! Just click on the tag 'firebase', look how many questions have the tags in the title... I think it is good practise to include the tags in the title

Comment: @J.Doe See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles . Many people doing something doesn't mean it should be done like that. Depending on specific tags, you might have a huge number of newbies who simply do not understand how to *properly* write up questions.

Comment: Thanks guys I've solved my problem and that's true I'm using stackoverflow for a long time but a recently registered, I gonna use tag in the next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using firebase auth, you can use the `listUsers` function of the [admin module](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) (limited to 1000 items per page)

But you can also have a `/users` node in your database that store users id and additionnal users information. Then it will be very easy to count the number of nodes under you `/users` node.